# Index messing up my page limits

Tags: indexing

I'm new to LaTex and yesterday I started doing a report and I notice something very weird. When I use /printindex, all the pages next to it got their right margin completely messed up.

With Index 
[image: With Index]

Without Index:
[image: Without Index]

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex




\begin{document}

\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{22cm}

\title{....} %stuff here

\author{....} %more stuff

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\printindex

\section{Introdução}
\index{Introdução}


\begin{small}
\onehalfspacing

Introduction text

\end{small}



\end{document}
```

Best Regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the problem at hand. Without such code, it's going to be well-nigh impossible to diagnose what's going on, let alone propose a fix. Please be sure to mention, among other things, which TeX distribution and which front end (i..e, editing program) you use.

Comment: Setting `\textwidth` and `\textheight` after `\begin{document}` is going to give several problems.

Comment: I took it off and now it seems fixed. Is it important or should I leave it like that?

Answer (score 2):

Setting `\textwidth` and `\textheight` after `\begin{document}` is not a good idea.

What happens is that those settings are not looked at when normal input is found, but in some circumstances (and doing `\printindex` is among these) the parameters would start to have effect.

If you measure the output without `\printindex`, you'll discover it has not a width of 16cm, but the usual 345pt (just a bit over 12cm).

Note that you don't want a text width of 16 centimeters without also changing the margins. If you really want to set the height and width, use `geometry`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % recommended for Portuguese
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage[textwidth=16cm,textheight=22cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\title{....} %stuff here

\author{....} %more stuff

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\printindex

\section{Introdução}
\index{Introdução}


\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```